# How to click using class

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

i am learning how to write scripts in tampermonkey(chrome) by using Jquery. I have a problem, i want to click on GO 1 and next to click on GO 2. I tried using class but it not works for me.

This is example of code in website.

```
<div class="location">
            <a onclick="go_1.submit();" title="Go">
                <form action="/place" method="post" name="go_1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                </form>
                <img src="img/location/s/Go 1.jpg" height="40" width="50" alt="Place" One="" border="0">
            </a>
            </div>

<div class="location">
            <a onclick="go_2.submit();" title="Go 2">
                <form action="/place" method="post" name="go_2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
                </form>
                <img src="img/location/s/Go 2.jpg" height="40" width="50" alt="Place2" Two="" border="0">
            </a>
            </div>
```

I tried using this function but it not works :(

```html
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://website.xx/xx
// @grant        none
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @run-at       document-end

// ==/UserScript==


$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("go_1.submit")[0].click();
});



$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("go_2.submit")[0].click();
});
```

I was searching here for answers but i found nothing. English is not my main language so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not a problem description. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and read any errors. `go_1.submit` and `go_2.submit` aren’t class names.

Comment: *it not works* is not a problem description. Please see [ask] and [mcve], and then [edit] your post to clearly explain what *not works* means. It's your job to clearly tell us what problem you're having, and ask a *specific question*. You've not explained a problem at all, and haven't asked any sort of question, much less a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the HTML you posted has a class named `go_2` nor `submit`. You can click on your `a` tags by selecting them using other attributes, like their title.

```
document.querySelector('[title="Go"]').click();
```